# How to access nested array

Tags: arrays, json, coldfusion, cfloop

[image]

I am trying to access recipeIngredient in this array.

I have tried this:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(contents)#" index="i">
<cfoutput>
 #i.recipeIngredient#<br>
</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

I am getting an error "You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class coldfusion.runtime.Array as a structure with members."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using nested data, so you need to check for the existance of that particular struct that has the key `recipeIngredient` to output it.

In that case I wouldn't iterate the arrays by **index**, because CFML gives the wonderful possibilty to cfloop an array by using the attribute *array* and iterate it by its **items**, which feels more natural and easier to read.

Also, don't add `<cfoutput>` to the inner body of loops, because it adds more overhead to your cfengine. Instead, embrace the loops with cfoutput.

```
<cfoutput>
   <cfloop array="#contents#" item="item">
      <cfif isStruct( item ) and structKeyExists( item, "recipeIngredient")>
         <cfloop array="#item.recipeIngredient#" item="ingredient">
            #ingredient#<br>
         </cfloop>
      </cfif>

      <!--- for looping over a struct like recipeinstructions use collection attribute--->
      <cfif isStruct( item ) and structKeyExists( item, "recipeinstructions")>
         <cfloop collection="#item.recipeinstructions#" item="key">
           Value for key '#encodeForHTML(key)#': #encodeForHTML( item.recipeinstructions[key])#<br>
         </cfloop>
      </cfif>

   </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly for recipeingredient. Can you assist me with recipeinstructions? I am getting an error "Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values." when using your code for that structure.

Comment: Just edited the answer for that

Comment: Hi @AndreasRu. I'm so annoyed. Your solution works perfectly on the example I provided. However on [link] (https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/chicken-madras) it doesnt work. I will add the screenshot of this websites Json. It seems that this website is using the correct format for the structured data. Will you be able to have a look why your solution is not working here?

Answer (score 0):

Another way of looping is to use an `index` loop instead of an `array` loop or a `collection` loop and then loop from 1 to the `arrayLen()` of the array.  Either way is fine.  I typically prefer this method as being easier to read when accessing deeper nested level structures and arrays.  If you choose to use this, you can refactor your code as follows.  if you would like to see, I created a [working demo](https://trycf.com/gist/5e58692f4767f33d6550868b1ae61706/acf2018?theme=monokai) here.

```
<cfoutput>
    <h4>Ingredients</h4>
    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(contents['recipeIngredient'])#">
        #contents['recipeIngredient'][i]# <br>
    </cfloop>

    <h4>Instructions</h4>
    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(contents['recipeInstructions'])#">
        #contents['recipeInstructions'][i]['@type']# <br>
        #contents['recipeInstructions'][i]['name']# <br>
        #contents['recipeInstructions'][i]['text']# <br>
        #contents['recipeInstructions'][i]['url']# <br>
        #contents['recipeInstructions'][i]['image']# <br>
        <br>
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```