# Looping over a nested array

Tags: arrays, json, data-structures, coldfusion, cfloop

I am struggling to get this to work. I need to loop over the structure but I am getting an error: "Object of type class coldfusion.runtime.Struct cannot be used as an array"

[image]

[image: Part of the same JSON]

This is what I tried.

```
<cfoutput>
<h4>Ingredients</h4>
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(contents['recipeIngredient'])#">
    #contents['recipeIngredient'][i]# <br>
</cfloop> 
This works...

<h4>Instructions</h4>
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(contents['recipeInstructions'])#">
    #contents['recipeInstructions'][i]['@type']# <br>
    #contents['recipeInstructions'][i]['name']# <br>
    #contents['recipeInstructions'][i]['text']# <br>
    #contents['recipeInstructions'][i]['url']# <br>
    #contents['recipeInstructions'][i]['image']# <br>
    <br>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
This doesnt work...
```

I am getting an error for "Instructions": "Object of type class coldfusion.runtime.Struct cannot be used as an array".

Can anyone please assist? I have been around in circles for 2 days.

Comment: Don't just [copy and paste code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72155776) without understanding what that code is doing.  That snippet was designed for a different data structure.  If you look at your screen shot above, clearly it doesn't contain all of the same elements, like `contents['recipeInstructions'][i]['url']` causing an error.

Comment: I'm trying to understand. This structured data is being implemented differently on different websites. The above solution works on some but on many it breaks. That is why I have now added the data from these websites that break the code. I don't understand why it's breaking so hence my question. I'm new to structures and arrays and doing my best ok.

Comment: What other sites post or do is not relevant. Just copying some code and pasting it to yours won't work. Relevant is what data is available to you within the data contents. E.g. I can't see anything about an URL in your recepieInstructions container, just @type and text.

Comment: What is the data that you are trying to loop through?

Answer (score 1):

The code you are using has references to property names that do not appear to exist from the image you provided. I don't see `name`, `url`, or `image` anywhere in the provided structs.

If you are trying to use the same cfm for several different data formats, then you need to at least make sure that the [struct keys exist](https://cfdocs.org/structkeyexists). Or even better, just use the keys that do exists. You could potentially do something like this:

```
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(contents['recipeInstructions'])#">
  <cfset instruction = contents.recipeInstructions[i]/>
  <cfloop item="key" collection="#instruction#">
    #instruction[key]#<br>
  </cfloop>
  <br>
</cfloop>
```